# Trouble with encoding special characters for tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am having a lot of trouble with encoding character '/' in order to use it in streaming twitter api with twython. When it is tried without the encoding, the 'EUR/USD' gives an error code [401](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses). Note, with other search queries it works normally and does not produce this error.

I have tried doing this in a couple of ways.
First:

```
'EUR/USD'.replace('/','%2F')
```

but the search is not returning anything.

I also tried:

```
urllib.quote('EUR/USD', '')
```

and while the output with print is the same (EUR%2FUSD) the search is still not returning any results.

Finally I tried double encoding:

```
urllib.quote(urllib.quote('EUR/USD', ''),'')
```

where I get EUR%252FUSD but still no results.

Furthermore, when searching for just EURUSD, search does work properly but only when it is preceded by the symbol $ (e.g. $EURUSD) in the tweet itself.
In case the dollar sign is missing search also won't detect the tweet. (e.g. just EURUSD)

This is how it works:

```
querystring = 'EURUSD'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('key','secret')
auth.set_access_token('key','secret')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        pprint.pprint([status.user.name,removeNonAscii(status.text),status.lang])

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=querystring, languages=['en'])
```

Anyone has an idea of what might be going on here?

Comment: What happens if you just search for 'EUR/USD'? Also, can you post a SSCCE?

Comment: In case of 'eur/usd' It gives a 401 error. I've updated the question with a SSCCE I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Tweepy has changed since you posted your question. Are you still having a problem?